# Merge C program and VHDL bitstream via "make" (i.e. using a Makefile)

Tags: c, makefile, vhdl, fpga, bitstream

I am trying to test the VHDL AVR8 soft processor found on Gadget Factory on a Digilent Nexys II (Spartan 3E) Development board. The project includes a Makefile for compiling a C (or other) software program and merging it with the FPGA bitstream so there is no need to resynthesize the HDL with every iteration of the software.

When I execute 'make' I get the following error associated with data2mem:

```
Merging Verilog Mem file with Xilinx bitstream: main.bit
data2mem -bm bin/top_avr_core_v8_bd.bmm -bt bin/top_avr_core_v8.bit -bd main.mem -o b main.bit
process_begin: CreateProcess(NULL, data2mem -bm bin/top_avr_core_v8_bd.bmm -bt bin/top_avr_core_v8.bit -bd main.mem -o b main.bit, ...) failed.
make (e=2): The system cannot find the file specified.
make: *** [main.bit] Error 2
```

I am executing 'make' in the same directory containing the VHDL project files, and I even have a blank 'main.bit' file in the directory.

Does anyone have any ideas about what's going on here? Does my blank 'main.bit' file need to be formatted a certain way or placed in a different location?

The following is a link to my Makefile:

[Makefile](https://www.dropbox.com/s/qihd5nfxwae3rqj/Makefile)

Other information to note: I'm new to using Makefiles in general, let alone for the specific purpose of merging software with an FPGA bitstream file. Also, I am attempting this on a Windows 7 machine in command prompt.

Thanks in advance.

Edit: Here's a [link](http://gadgetforge.gadgetfactory.net/gf/project/avr_core/) to the AVR8 soft processor on Gadget Factory, and here's the AVR8 [source](http://gadgetforge.gadgetfactory.net/gf/project/avr_core/frs/).

Comment: Also provide a link to the project on Gadget Factory, if you want us to see if they might have provided anything else related.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Offhand I'd say make cannot invoke the `data2mem` program.  Do you have such a program on your system?  Is the directory containing it in your PATH variable?  Does it run properly?  For example, can you type in that command line yourself at the command prompt and have it work properly?

Comment: Hi MadScientist, thank you for the comment. `data2mem` does exist on my system. I have added its directory to my PATH variable, but it does not run when I type the command in command line by itself. Any thoughts on what to do now?

Comment: You must figure out how to get it to run for you, before it will run for make.  Probably a good first step is for you to update your question with the results of running the command line by hand: "_it does not run_" is not a very helpful description of the problem.

Answer (score 1):

When you say a "blank" main.bit, I assume you mean a "fully populated except for the memory that I want to put the program into" main.bit... otherwise nothings going to work!

It sounds like you do not have `data2mem` on your path - are you sure you are running your makefile from a command window/shell which includes the xilinx paths?

On Windows, there is a specific icon for this.   Alternatively you can open any old command prompt and run the settings32.bat (or settings64.bat) file from within the Xilinx install folder to get set up.  Or on linux, you can `source` the appropriate `.sh`/`.csh` file in your shell.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, Martin. I already had a separate .bit file generated for the design, but per the settings in my makefile, `data2mem` outputs a .bit file called "main.bit."

Turns out `data2mem` was not in my path after all.